# How to do Linq query update

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I have the following method to return the data of two entities.

```
public List<Object> GetDados()
{
    var sendFilter = new Filter<MessageSent>();
    //employeeFilter.Add(x => x.Name, name);
    sendFilter.Add(x => x.MessageSentSeq, ID_GROUP_SEND);
    // You can add more filters

    MessageSentService svc = new MessageSentService();
    var messages = svc.Find(sendFilter).ToList();

    var employees = new EmployeeService().GetAll();

    var query =
        from employee in employees
        join message in messages
        on employee.EmployeeId equals message.EmployeeId
        select new
        {
            MessageSentId = message.MessageSentId,
            //EmployeeId = message.EmployeeId,
            //MessageSentSeq = message.MessageSentSeq,
            Name = employee.Name,
            Surname = employee.Surname,
            Mobile = employee.Mobile,
            Email = employee.Email,
            Status = "N"
        };
    return query.ToList<Object>();
}
```

Call

```
ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Form));
List<Object> Send;

Send = GetDados();
gvSent.DataSource = Send;
```

When doing send I would like to update the record that is inside **object** `var query` that in turn populates my grid

I need to **set** the `status` field with `S` at the end of everything I updated my database with the items that were sent correctly.

Comment: Which LINQ provider are you using? LINQ is just a technology for querying enumerables and doesn't have anything to do with modifying database records. Are you using LINQ to SQL? Entity Framework? Something else?

Comment: @Jacob Yes I understand that and to consult, I'm still studying! I am using Sqlite with Entity. Just want to know if I can change a certain field in my list that I retrieved through Linq?

Answer (score 0):

Because your function returns a `List<Object>`, you'll be unable to modify those properties without using Reflection or some other drastic measure. If you plan on this data being modifiable, you'll need to make sure the data you're returning is typed. First define a simple class:

```
class Dado
{
    public string MessageSentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public bool Mobile { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

...then modify your function to return instances of this type:

```
public List<Dado> GetDados()
{
    var sendFilter = new Filter<MessageSent>();
    //employeeFilter.Add(x => x.Name, name);
    sendFilter.Add(x => x.MessageSentSeq, ID_GROUP_SEND);
    // You can add more filters

    MessageSentService svc = new MessageSentService();
    var messages = svc.Find(sendFilter).ToList();

    var employees = new EmployeeService().GetAll();

    return (
        from employee in employees
        join message in messages
        on employee.EmployeeId equals message.EmployeeId
        select new Dado
        {
            MessageSentId = message.MessageSentId,
            //EmployeeId = message.EmployeeId,
            //MessageSentSeq = message.MessageSentSeq,
            Name = employee.Name,
            Surname = employee.Surname,
            Mobile = employee.Mobile,
            Email = employee.Email,
            Status = "N"
        }
    ).ToList();
}
```

Now, in your code after populating the grid can do something like:

```
foreach (var dado in Send) {
    dado.Status = "S";
}
```